# How to show all function prototypes of a C++ file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, function-prototypes

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I want to show all the function prototypes that I have in a file at one glance!

Comment: you can try extensions like vs10x codeMap

Comment: Awesome, this is just what I was looking for, thanks @mikus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just promoting my comment to an answer:

you can try extensions like:

[VS10x Code Map](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2)

Im using it happily for years with different technologies. The only drawback is that it takes a bit to map with huge files.

Alternative is just a class view (ctrl+W,C) panel in Visual Studio, but it's still poor, not very configurable and doesn't show much.